Intermittent cursor visibility in NCURSES
I'm teaching myself C (c17) and playing with ncurses.
I have written a function that clears the screen and draws a random number of colored period characters in random X, Y locations. (I've removed the color stuff in this code sample.)
I use curs_set(0) and 90-95% of the time this works correctly. Intermittently, though, the cursor remains visible.
I ssh to a Debian 11 server from both Windows 11 and a Mac Mini 2 and the problem is the same.
Any ideas?
Source that reproduces the problem:
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void) {
        initscr();
        curs_set(0);
        timeout(0);
        nodelay(stdscr, TRUE);
        start_color();
        bkgd(COLOR_PAIR(0));
        for (int i = 0; i < (rand() % (COLS * 2)) + COLS / 2; i++) {
                char ch;
                int x, y;
                do {
                        y = rand() % LINES;
                        x = rand() % COLS;
                        ch = mvinch(y, x) & A_CHARTEXT;
                } while (ch != ' ');
                curs_set(0);
                mvprintw(y, x, ".");
                curs_set(0);
        }
        curs_set(0);
        refresh();
        curs_set(0);
        struct timespec req = {2, 0};
        int result = nanosleep(&req, NULL);
        timeout(1);
        nodelay(stdscr, FALSE);
        clear();
        endwin();
        flushinp();
        return 0;
}


When I run this on a Mac Terminal the cursor is always visible. You should check the return value of curs_set(), it returns ERR if it can't change the cursor visibility.

@Barmar Excellent idea. I checked the return value of curs_set() and it's not ERR (it's always 0) on the runs where the cursor was visible.

Does it happen when the last char was printed on the left/right column? top/bottom row? I ssh (with PuTTY, Windows) to a Debian 12 server and couldn't make the cursor blink as long as I kept one single curs_set(0); before refresh();.

@pmg I stripped my code down even further, and moved curs_set(0) to after refresh() and I still get the intermittent cursor. It does seem like it's always in the bottom right corner of the screen, though.

The bottom right corner may need special treatment (inside ncurses) to deal with screen scrolling; if you can try to avoid it, it may solve your issues.

Maybe you can play with scrollok() (or leaveok() or other options) to enable all points to be selected? ... as in scrollok(stdscr, FALSE);

I commented out all the calls to curs_set(0) in my copy and didn't see any difference in the results. The cursor was always visible in the same place at the end.

@pmg I had the same idea about prohibiting the bottom right space. However, scrollok(stdscr, FALSE) just might have done the trick. I have not been able to reproduce since I added that line. Thanks! EDIT: I spoke too soon. So I'll just prevent usage of that final space.

@pmg I just noticed two things. 1. Blocking the bottom right space didn't seem to help. 2. I don't seed the RNG, so the pattern is always the same. Even so, the cursor is still an intermittent guest.

Did you try blocking the whole last line? Maybe create a new window instead of using stdscr? 1st option feels like losing a lot of real estate, 2nd option feels like a lot of work for something so simple!

As another data point, I cannot reproduce on Ubuntu 22.04. I never see the cursor. Even after I added seeding the RNG.

endwin will restore the cursor; I don't see any other calls which would do that.  MacOS Terminal should work properly.  If you have a reproducible problem with Windows Terminal, that would be a bug in that program.

@pmg I'm beginning to wonder if ncurses itself (or using it over SSH) is just flaky? I don't recall seeing issues like this in Nethack. There must be some solution. Anyway, I added a box to stdscr and I'm seeing intermittent problems: cursor in middle, blinking cursor, and one time, the box border was scrambled. I'm starting to feel really bad about debugging such things with trial and error rather than working on my program.

@pmg I finally tried using a new window rather than attempting to work with stdscr. I think that may have solved all of the problems. Thanks again for the help!

I don't know the internals of ncurses or really how everything (your code, ncurses, the OS, the device driver(s), the actual physical hardware screen, ssh, the terminal emulator, ...) interacts. Reason I suggested using a "virtual ncurses window" is that stdscr feels more "connected", more hardware-y and problematic.

Glad you got it working, sorry for all the windowing extra work!

@Barmar This morning I ran it on my Mac, too. It worked beautifully. However, I still have issues with identical code over SSH on a Linux server. My assumption is that whatever controls the terminal occasionally drops data and I get the paint issues that cause the visual glitches.
